# Select from SQL single row and set to php array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to select a single row names `news_images` which contains record like this :

> name.jpg,image.jpg,randomimagerame.jpg

These pictures does not have similar names, so I want to set them in array, here is my code :

```
$info = array($row['news_image']);
print_r($info);
echo  $info[0] . ", " . $info[1] . " and " . $info[2] . ".";
```

I got error :

> Array ( [0] => name.jpg,image.jpg,randomimagerame.jpg )
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\PORTAL\htdocs\KARGI\news.php on line 84
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\PORTAL\htdocs\KARGI\news.php on line 84
>   name.jpg,image.jpg,randomimagerame.jpg, and .

How can I make this work ? I want result to be like this :

```
$info[0] = name.jpg
$info[1] = image.jpg
$info[2] = randomimagerame.jpg
```

Comment: Do NOT store delimiter separated lists into the DB! read over "db normalization" .

Comment: Thanks for answer i'll change it.

Comment: _i'll change it..._ Perfect! You'll have a much easier life :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` : **[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

```
 $info = explode(',',$row['news_image']);
 print_r($info);
```